# Float right is not working in IE 7 but works in FF IE8

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have this code

```
<div id="facebook_bar"> 
  <div style="float:left;">
  <img src="images/topbar_followus.png" width="70" height="25" /> 
  <img src="images/topbar_twitIcon.png" width="30" height="25" /> 
  <img src="images/topbar_fbicon.png" width="30" height="25" />
  </div>
    <div id="newsletter_box"> 


   <img src="images/topbar_subscribe.png" width="220" height="25" />
      <input type="text" name="cm-ktkykk-ktkykk" id="ktkykk-ktkykk" />
      <input type="image" src="images/btn_submit.png" width="55" height="25" />

      </div>
  </div>
```

css is

```
#facebook_bar {
 background-color:#323334;
 height:30px;
 padding-top:15px;
 padding-left:20px;
 padding-right:20px;
}
#newsletter_box {
 float:right;
 /*margin-top:-30px;*/

}
```

The right hand div is showing on next line after the first div not on the same line

Comment: Any reason why you aren't just using `float:left` for both with % widths to adjust horizontal position? Easiest way to get two divs sitting side by side IMO

Comment: Actually, I can't reproduce this problem. I copied the CSS and HTML into a blank template and it just works across the mentioned browsers. Your problem lies somewhere else. Try to provide a self-contained example, i.e. from `<html>` until with `</html>` so that we can just copy'n'paste'n'run it.

Comment: It is working now , i think when i added inline float left then IE somewhat did't loaded that one. But now its fine. ACtually initially i was not having first div box , then i added that so that it can float left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initally posted this as a comment but might as well give you it as an answer.

Why don't you just use `float:left` for both `#newsletter_box` and the inline floated div. This will ensure they both sit at the same position vertically, you can then adjust the horizontal positioning using % widths.

I'd also check out [this](http://www.complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/) article to clear the float because you have images involved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to float the left bar as well, add `float:left` to #facebook_bar.

Comment: He already did it inline: `<div style="float:left;">`. The `#facebook_bar` is the wrapper.

Comment: You're right. (My answer was from when there was only CSS posted to the question, didn't catch the updated version)